# How to convert multiple rows into one row with multiple columns using Pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a log file that comes in as 1 column and each record consist of multiple rows. Each record is delimited by an empty(blank) row. How can I move each row of record into its own column(s) and I have to do it dynamically? Be gentle...im very new.

```
Column1
----------------------------
**empty row -Begin Record 1
row1data1
row1data2
row1data3
**empty row -Begin Record 2
row2data1
row2data2
row2data3
NULL
row2data5
**empty row - Begin Record 3
.
.
.
```

The results I would like:

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4   Column5    
----------------------------------------------------
row1data1   row1data2   row1data3    
row2data1   row2data2   row2data3   NULL      row2data5
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this is coming from a file how do you distinguish between NULL and empty row? Or is this log file actually a table? We need a bit more detail here about your situation so we can offer some help.

Comment: i pulled in a csv file as a table and did a find and replace of the original delimiter wich was a line of dashes -------------------------------- and replace with an empty " " so i can recognize where a new record begins.  NULL values are already in the log

Comment: Do they have a string literal "NULL" or something? Typically in a csv you don't have null, you have an empty string. Help us help you here. Do you now have this data in a table? Are there always exactly 5 columns? At this point we are shooting in the dark with an invisible weapon at an unknown target.

Comment: Here is an excellent article explaining the kinds of things you should post so others can help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Yes i have it in a table...should i work directly from the csv file? The NULL values are literal strings "NULL" and NO...its not always 5 rows that i want into columns. Sorry but the data is sensitive or else i would post.

Comment: Nobody wants real data. But post the table structure with some fake data that is representative of your challenge and what the output should be for that data. I suspect what you are going to need is a dynamic crosstab or a dynamic pivot.